# Problem with Creating Site collection from custom site template in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, site-template, publishing

I am trying to generate the site template forcefully and trying to create site collection with the template and getting the following Error.

****Sorry, something went wrong
The list "Shared Documents" doesn't exist.  Please fix the ListUrl attribute.
TECHNICAL DETAILS****

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
Correlation ID: 9590dc9d-a0dc-3000-defc-f93fc5b7a7bf

Date and Time: 3/9/2017 10:21:03 PM

Can anyone please let us know the specific reason for this and a resolution for this?
I have enabled Publishing future enabled and generating the template, I got succeeded for another site which is also enabled with Publishing future.

Is there any other approach to move my site to another site collection.

Answer (score 0):

Test with Powershell and exporting and importing the site.

Export

```
 Export-SPWeb -Force -Identity $urlOrigin -path $cmpFileName -IncludeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions All -Verbose
```

Import

```
Import-SPWeb $urlDestination -Path $cmpFileName -IncludeUserSecurity -Force -Verbose
```